# Send token stored in cookie to server and get boolean return

Tags: javascript, cookies, freemarker

I dont know if this is even possible to do. I have searched a lot on the web with no big help to prove that it could work.

What i want to do is to grab a token saved in a cookie. Then put this cookie in a freemarker function call. So then the server will reply true or false. Depending on if the token is valid or not. If it is valid the content will be written.

```
<#if (object.somefunction (GrabTokenAndSendIt) )!false> Show Content </#if>
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Im new to freemarker. So any tips is helpful here.
I use the following command in javascript to grab the token from the cookie

```
localStorage.getItem('userToken')
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker doesn't prove anything to access HTTP or servlet related stuff out of the box. It's up to the web application framework to expose such things to it, if it wants to, but usually it shouldn't. FreeMarker is mostly used as MVC View, and as such, it shouldn't deal with non-presentation issues like cookies. You should check that cookie in the MVC Controller, then put into the date-model (aka. template context) if the visitor is authorized to see that conditional content or not.